# querying relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm practicing laravel and im confused in querying relations I have two tables (users and roles)

in my user model i have

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function role(){
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

and in my role model i have

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

this is my table structure for role

[image]

and this my table structure for users

[image]

how can i query the roles base on users table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your relationship in your both model:

**User Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class,'role_id');
    }
```

**Role Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function user(){
   return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

And your query like:

**Updated Answer**

```
$user = User::find(1);
dd($user->roles());
```

Comment: sir tried it on laravel tinker the result is just like this => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#2923}

Comment: $rsltusers = User::find(1)->role; when I tried this on tinker the error is Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
`roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 1 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null and `roles`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)'

Comment: @Beginner: Are you change your model relationship which is given by me?

Comment: same result sir Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#2944} is this the real output? i tried it on tinker

Answer (score 1):

You need to change relationships in both models:

```
 use SoftDeletes;

public function role(){
     return $this->hasOne(Role::class,'id','role_id');
}
```

and in other model as well:

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'role_id','id');
}
```

and then call it as:

```
User::find(1)->role();
```

Try this it will work...

Comment: i got this => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#2942} im trying it on tinker

Comment: have you tried to store it in a variable and use the variable?

Comment: also use https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-eloquent-relationships for better understanding of relationships in laravel.

Comment: same result sir Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#2924}

Answer (score 1):

*app/Model/User*

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Role", "role_id", "role_id");
    }
```

*app/Model/Role*

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Model\Users");
    }
```

further read : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 0):

If Laravel recognizes your relation `User::find(1)->role` should work.

Just try `dd(User::find(1)->role);` anywhere in your code.

Comment: i tried it before but i got the error Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
`roles` where `roles`.`user_id` = 3 and `roles`.`user_id` is not null and `roles`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

Answer (score 0):

User Model

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function role(){
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class,'role_id','id);
}
```

Role Model

```
use SoftDeletes;

public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id','role_id');
}
```

Update your code like this and it works.